# Javascript with a for in loop

Tags: for-in-loop

working on the follow code. Having some issues with taking the user input from the day and the temp. I have a start but again running into an issue with Step 2 & 3 unable to pass the information to the array and figure out how to display it. Any insight and direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
var temperatures = [];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];


var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var takeTemps = function () {
    //###STEP 2
    //Get the user inputted temp, validate it making sure it's a number
    //if it's valid add it to the temperatures array at the index that
    // corresponds with the day of week, e.g. 0 for Monday, 2 for Wednesday
    var userTemp=(parseFloat($("tempIn").value));
    while (!isNaN(tempIn)==true)
    {
        alert("Please enter a numeric value");
        $("tempIn").focus();
    }


    //This gets the value from the selected menu option
    var index = $("daySelect").value;

    for(var dayTemp in temperatures)
    {
        var daily=temperatures[index]

    }

    //remove this when done, this just tests your menu you wrote for step 1
    alert( index + " indexes day " + days[index]+ userTemp);

    //Call displayTemps ONLY if the temp input was valid.
    displayTemps();

    //EXTRA work / not credit
    // have it auto advance the selected day in the menu
    // by assigning into $("daySelect").value 
    // If it was on Sunday change it to Monday and only on valid input

}

var displayTemps = function () {
    //###STEP 3
    //loop through non-undefined indexes in the temperatures array
    //appended them to tempString adding the day .e.x 
    //Tuesday: 89
    //Friday: 98
    //display the string to the page by setting the value of the textarea
    //
    //In the same loop sum the temperatures and count 
    // how many there are so you can calculate the average
    // and output the average temp on the page.
    tempString = "";
    tempTemp = 0;
    for(var i in temperatures) {
    tempString += index + ": " + temperatures[i];
    }

    document.write(tempString  + "<br>");
    var average =tempTemp+10;
    $("tempList").value=tempString;
    $("avgOut").value=average;
}

window.onload = function () {
    $("addTemp").onclick = takeTemps;

    //###STEP 1
    //Use a for loop here to write options to the select for each day of the week
    // <option value="0">Monday</option>
    // using += here with innerHTML property takes the existing values and concats this on the end
    for (var i =0; i<7; i++)
    {
    $("daySelect").innerHTML +=  "<option value=\""+   i + "\">" + days[i] + "</option>\n";
    $("daySelect").value = ""; 
        //var day=i-1;
        //var day = days[i];
        }
    $("tempIn").focus();
```

### }

Struggles with Step 2 and 3 Beleive i have #1 good to go I have enclosed the HTML for reference

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src=script.js></script>
        <head>
        <body>
            <section>
                <select id="daySelect">
                    <option value="">Select a day</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="tempIn">
                <input type="button" id="addTemp" value="add temperature">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="tempList">Temperature List</label>
                <br>
                <textarea id="tempList" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea>
                <br>
                <label>Average Temperature</label>
                <input type="text" id="avgOut" disabled>
            </section>
        </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to provide more specific information about which part of the code you are concerned with, and especially, **provide the HTML code as well** since that would enable us to see more clearly what you are trying to do.

When you are done, I will edit this answer and you will get appropriate guidance.

Keep coding!

---

#### EDIT

*Take a look:*

```
var userTemp=(parseFloat($("tempIn").value));
while (!isNaN(tempIn)==true)
{
    alert("Please enter a numeric value");
    $("tempIn").focus();
}
```

Looking at this little piece of code from "Step 2", I can think of a number of bugs already. Of course I'm not sure since I haven't seen your HTML yet, but it seems like:

1. You have put the value of the input into a variable named `userTemp`, yet you are checking for a variable named `"tempIn"` for validation. The second one probably doesn't exist at that point in time. `"tempIn"` was the name of your DOM element, not the JS variable you've assigned its value. **You have to check for the** `userTemp` variable.
2. In your validation, you are checking for the opposite of isNaN. NaN means "Not a Number", so the opposite of that would be actually number, so the statement is wrong. Not to mention that in this, you would not need to explicitly express "==true", **you can check like this:** `while(isNaN(userTemp))`
3. If you want to iterate a while statement for validation until you get a valid number, you need to put the variable assignment **inside** the while statement, since you'll need to try to assign the new number each time the validation loop iterates.

---

#### EDIT 2 - finished

Your code is live here:

https://codepen.io/bradib0y/pen/OBEdvp?editors=1010

Please note that if you are working your way through a course and this was your assessment, you've gained exactly nothing with me making these tasks for you. You will only gain from getting throught these challenges yourself.

I suggest to spend at least 1 hour with analyzing this code step by step and try to replicate it in a similar project. If you still have struggle with understanding, do yourself a favor and start over with basic javascript once again. You will be an expert on this within a week, if you put the basics down right. But if you still can't grasp the basics and keep pushing forward with more complex issues, you will have a hard time.

Comment: Ok I am having concerns with Step 2 and 3 I think that I have some information that is good and there is obviously some that isn't but I am new and have a lot of work to do to be better. I have enclosed the HTML file info also